# In TensorFlow, how can I get nonzero values and their indices from a tensor with python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, indices

I want to do something like this.
Let's say we have a tensor A.

```
A = [[1,0],[0,4]]
```

And I want to get nonzero values and their indices from it.

```
Nonzero values: [1,4]  
Nonzero indices: [[0,0],[1,1]]
```

There are similar operations in Numpy.
`np.flatnonzero(A)` return indices that are non-zero in the flattened A.
`x.ravel()[np.flatnonzero(x)]` extract elements according to non-zero indices.
Here's [a link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) for these operations.

How can I do somthing like above Numpy operations in Tensorflow with python?
(Whether a matrix is flattened or not doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can achieve same result in Tensorflow using [not_equal](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#not_equal) and [where](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#where) methods.

```
zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
where = tf.not_equal(A, zero)
```

`where` is a tensor of the same shape as `A` holding `True` or `False`, in the following case

```
[[True, False],
 [False, True]]
```

This would be sufficient to select zero or non-zero elements from `A`. If you want to obtain indices you can use `where`method as follows:

```
indices = tf.where(where)
```

`where` tensor has two `True` values so `indices` tensor will have two entries. `where` tensor has rank of two, so entries will have two indices:

```
[[0, 0],
 [1, 1]]
```

Comment: How will you get the array from the boolean matrix? I dont think boolean indexing is implemented yet

Comment: @martianwars see the link to `where` documentation. It accepts booleans and produces a tensor of corresponding indices.

Comment: No I meant the values at those indices. I did it using a boolean mask

Comment: How can you get just the indices of the rows which are completely zero ?

Comment: Define `zero` tensor as a tensor of zeros with the same shape as your row. For example, use [`zeros_like`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/constant_op/constant_value_tensors#zeros_like) to define it @Qubix

Comment: @SergiiGryshkevych I tried this, using `tf.zeros()` of 1x4 and using `tf.not_equal()` between that vector, and a 200x4 tensor. The result was matrix of 200x4 of the comparison of every element to zero, and not vectors...

Comment: re "And I want to get nonzero values"  Please show how to get the values at those indices. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

```
#assume that an array has 0, 3.069711,  3.167817.
mask = tf.greater(array, 0)
non_zero_array = tf.boolean_mask(array, mask)
```

Comment: Negative values can also be non-zero.
This is not returning indices.

Answer (score 0):

What about using sparse tensors.

```py
>>> A = [[1,0],[0,4]]
>>> sparse = tf.sparse.from_dense(A)
>>> sparse.values.numpy(), sparse.indices.numpy()
(array([1, 4], dtype=int32), array([[0, 0],
        [1, 1]]))
```

Comment: This is a good answer for actual sparse tensors, but I have the feeling this could be inefficient for dense tensors. I can well imagine, that there are memory overheads from the conversion to the sparse tensor. Personally, I would use Sergii's answer, since it is more transparent.

Comment: @André, good point. I took a look to the [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.8.0/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py#L102-L131) and is very similar to Sergii's suggestion.
```python
indices = tf.where_v2(tf.not_equal(A, tf.zeros_like(A)))
values = array_ops.gather_nd(A, indices)
```