# Remove zero vectors from a matrix in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Just like the question says, I'm trying to remove all zeros vectors (i.e `[0, 0, 0, 0]`) from a tensor.

Given:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.19999981,  0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.4000001 ,  0.29999995,  0.10000002,  0.        ],
   ..., 
   [-0.5999999 ,  0.        , -0.0999999 , -0.20000005],
   [-0.29999971, -0.4000001 , -0.30000019, -0.5       ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]], dtype=float32)
```

I had tried the following code (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219414/in-tensorflow-how-can-i-get-nonzero-values-and-their-indices-from-a-tensor-with) SO):

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(10000, 4))

zeros_vector = tf.zeros(shape=(1, 4), dtype=tf.float32)
bool_mask = tf.not_equal(x, zero_vector)

omit_zeros = tf.boolean_mask(x, bool_mask)
```

But `bool_mask` seem also to be of shape (10000, 4), like it was comparing every element in the `x` tensor to zero, and not rows.

I thought about using `tf.reduce_sum` where an entire row is zero, but that will omit also rows like `[1, -1, 0, 0]` and I don't want that.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way would be to sum over the absolute values of the row, in this way it will not omit rows like `[1, -1, 0, 0]` and then compare it with a zero vector. You can do something like this:

```
intermediate_tensor = reduce_sum(tf.abs(x), 1)
zero_vector = tf.zeros(shape=(1,1), dtype=tf.float32)
bool_mask = tf.not_equal(intermediate_tensor, zero_vector)
omit_zeros = tf.boolean_mask(x, bool_mask)
```

Comment: can't believe I figured out `reduce_sum` and didn't think of using `abs`. seems like a legit solution, I will try to make sure it works and upvote + accept if applicable

Answer (score 1):

I tried solution by Rudresh Panchal and it doesn't work for me. Maybe due versions change. 
I found tipo in the first row: `reduce_sum(tf.abs(x), 1)` -> `tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(x), 1)`.

Also, bool_mask has rank 2 instead of rank 1, which is required:
*tensor: N-D tensor.
mask: K-D boolean tensor, K <= N and K must be known statically*. In other words, the shape of bool_mask must be for example [6] not [1,6]. `tf.squeeze` works well to reduce dimension.

Corrected code which works for me:

```
intermediate_tensor = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(x), 1)
zero_vector = tf.zeros(shape=(1,1), dtype=tf.float32)
bool_mask = tf.squeeze(tf.not_equal(intermediate_tensor, zero_vector))
omit_zeros = tf.boolean_mask(x, bool_mask)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the tensor to tf.bool and use it as a boolean mask:

```
boolean_mask = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.bool)              
no_zeros = tf.boolean_mask(x, boolean_mask, axis=0)
```